# How to display 10 records per page and then how to use pagination?

Tags: php

[One record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UiDJ.png)
[10 records loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukeKx.png)
I have trouble with displaying properly records, end after that i need to use pagination.
v_news.php

```html
<div class="news">
        <a href="index.php?ogloszenie='<?php $row['id_article']; ?>'">
    <div class="newstitle">
       <?php echo $row['title'];?>
    </div>
    <div class="newsauthor">
        <?php echo $row['username'];?>
    </div>
            <div class="newscomment">
                comments: 56
            </div>
    <div class="newsdate">
        <?php echo $row['timestamp'];?>
    </div>
        </a>

</div>
```

m_news.php

```js
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}else{
    
    $result = $Database->query("SELECT * FROM article LIMIT 0, 10");
    if($result->num_rows != 0){
        $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
        foreach ($rows as $row){
        include("views/v_news.php");
    
    } 
        
    
    }else{
        echo "No results";
    }
    
}
```

With foreach loop i have an error illegal string offset with $row['']. I don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

First try to fix your 2nd line of code in v_news.php.
You forgot to use "echo".

```
<a href="index.php?ogloszenie='<?php $row['id_article']; ?>'">
```

change to:

```
<a href="index.php?ogloszenie='<?php echo $row['id_article']; ?>'">
```

Comment: It's my mistake. I rewrote this few times.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch_assoc()` fetches one row, not all.

You can use a while loop which will end once fetch_assoc() stops returning new rows.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    include("views/v_news.php");
}
```

For pagination, you only need to change `LIMIT` parameters

i.e. `LIMIT 10,10` would be the second page data (10 total rows starting with row 10).

Also as **bobiczeq** pointed out you should ensure the `echo` statement appears in `<?php $row['id_article']; ?>` otherwise this is only empty.

Comment: I use fetch_all() instead of fetch_assoc(). But now it's showing me undefined index: id_artcle, title, itd.

Comment: do `var_dump($row);` and see what it shows `$row` is in v_news.php

Comment: How about `var_dump($result);` before you try the foreach. It must not be set correctly then. Since you were returning rows with fetch_assoc() though is there any reason you've since changed your mind on using that method like in my example above?

Answer (score 0):

I found correct answer.

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Now it's working correctly.

Comment: You're asking a question in an answer. That isn't how it works here. If you have another question, then you need to ask another and not in your answer.

Comment: I edited your answer in removing your asking for help on pagination.